P1001: Can't reach database server at viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net:26184
I'm working on a fullstack application using RedwoodJS.
The database was working when I was previously working on it, but when I came back to work on it I was consistently getting this error:

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net:26184.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
I've restarted and redeployed the database server, verified that the connection strings were correct, and tried making the startup sleep for 3 seconds.
